# Как добавить в Woocommerce функцию оплаты с платежной инструкцией на депозит в банк. счете

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет, тут такое дело впервые столкнулся с такой странной задачей, мне нужно на сайте Wordpress Woocommerce добавить необычный способ оплаты
Это будет сайт электронной коммерции, но без онлайн-платежей. Вместо этого платежная инструкция (депозит на банковский счет) будет включена в автоматически сгенерированный счет, который отправляется покупателю по электронной почте. Счет-фактура должен быть в формате PDF (кроме того, он также может быть отправлен по электронной почте, но PDF является обязательным требованием
Что можно сделать в моей случае?

Answer (score 0):

есть много решений

посмотри плагины, вот 1 из них

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).